# Gradle zip task ignores files having filename starting with .#

Tags: gradle

I have a simple gradle zip task,
I found out any files starting with .# from `input` folder are ignored

```
task zipIt(type: Zip) {
   from 'input/'
   archiveName = 'output.zip'
}
```

Does someone knows why is so? And how can I override this behavior so I include those files in the zip?

Later edit: 
Adding the file pattern explicitly doesn't seem to help

On the other hand, looking over @opal links led me to a solution:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner

task zipIt(type: Zip) {
    doFirst{
        DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude("**/.#*")
   }
   from 'input/'
   archiveName = 'output.zip'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember gradle used the same default excludes as [ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes) does. Have you tried including the file explicitly?

Please have some further reading [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/copy-git-specific-files/11970/2) and [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/filetree-and-default-excludes/7406/2).

Answer (score 2):

Expounding on Opal's answer, Gradle uses [ANT's default excludes](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes) which are as follows:

As of Ant 1.8.1 they are:

```
 **/*~
 **/#*#
 **/.#*
 **/%*%
 **/._*
 **/CVS
 **/CVS/**
 **/.cvsignore
 **/SCCS
 **/SCCS/**
 **/vssver.scc
 **/.svn
 **/.svn/**
 **/.DS_Store
```

Ant 1.8.2 adds the following default excludes:

```
 **/.git
 **/.git/**
 **/.gitattributes
 **/.gitignore
 **/.gitmodules
 **/.hg
 **/.hg/**
 **/.hgignore
 **/.hgsub
 **/.hgsubstate
 **/.hgtags
 **/.bzr
 **/.bzr/**
 **/.bzrignore
```

The `.#` is by default excluded. Updating your `build.gradle` file with a task similar to the following should allow you to overwrite the default excludes.

```
task copyPoundFiles(type: Copy) {
  from '/path/to/files'
  into '/dest/for/files'
  include '**/.#*'
}
```